# Convert Text File Encoding

Tags: encoding

I frequently encounter text files (such as subtitle files in my native language, [Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language)) with character encoding problems. These files are created on Windows, and saved with an unsuitable encoding (seems to be ANSI), which looks gibberish and unreadable, like this:

[image]

In Windows, one can fix this easily using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to convert the encoding to UTF-8, like below:

[image]

And the correct readable result is like this:

[image]

I've searched a lot for a similar solution on GNU/Linux, but unfortunately the suggested solutions (e.g [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/)) don't work. Most of all, I've seen people suggest **`iconv`** and **`recode`** but I have had no luck with these tools. I've tested many commands, including the followings, and all have failed:

```
$ recode ISO-8859-15..UTF8 file.txt
$ iconv -f ISO8859-15 -t UTF-8 file.txt > out.txt
$ iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 file.txt > out.txt
```

None of these worked!

I'm using Ubuntu-14.04 and I'm looking for a simple solution (either GUI or CLI) that works just as Notepad++ does.

One important aspect of being **"simple"** is that the user is not required to determine the source encoding; rather the source encoding should be automatically detected by the tool and only the target encoding should be provided by the user. But nevertheless, I will also be glad to know about a working solution that requires the source encoding to be provided.

If someone needs a test-case to examine different solutions, the above example is accessible [via this link](http://bayanbox.ir/download/2964843766286605028/file.txt).

Comment: Try: `vim '+set fileencoding=utf-8' '+wq' file.txt`.

Comment: Farsi should be `iso-639` but that doesn't seem to be available in either `iconv` or `recode`. At least, I don't see it in the output of `iconv -l`.

Comment: @muru I tested your suggestion with `vim` but it didn't work.

Comment: @SeyedMohammad still looked same?

Comment: @muru Yup! No change.

Comment: @SeyedMohammad that's odd, since for me initially the characters looked like something else altogether, and then vim changed then to

Comment: `iconv -f CP1256 -t UTF-8 ... ` or equivalently `iconv -f WINDOWS-1256 ...` appear to at least give the right *kind* of script - I suspect they are the nearest Arabic equivalents of the Persian characters? In my locale the letter order is L-R but I suspect that's corrected if you run `iconv` in a suitable R-L locale.

Comment: @terdon LoL. ISO 639 is a standard for **language** codes (two- and three-letter sequences that specify a language), not text encoding.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I know next to nothing about this sort of thing. Why are you telling me this? Should I assume that that explains why `iso-639` is not seen as an available encoding for `iconv` and `recode`? If so, what would the correct encoding be?

Comment: @terdon: Yes, you should assume that explanation IMHO. If the *correct* encoding means “in which code page were these files saved?”, then read the accepted answer.

Comment: Try ex (vim) `ex '+set fileencoding=utf-8' '+wq' <FILE>`. For me was the safest way. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823709/3223785

Comment: @muru you should create your own answer so I could upvote you !

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa alright, posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working solution I found is using the [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](http://code.visualstudio.com) text editor which is Freeware and available for Linux.

Open the file you want to convert its encoding in VS-Code. At the bottom of the window, there are a few buttons. One of them is related to the file encoding, as shown below:

[image]

Clicking this button pops up an overhead menu which includes two items. From this menu select the "Reopen with Encoding" option, just like below:

[image]

This will open another menu which includes a list of different encoding, as shown below. Now select "Arabic (Windows 1256)":

[image]

This will fix the gibberish text like this:

[image]

Now click the encoding button again and this time select the "Save with Encoding" option, just as below:

[image]

And in the new menu select the "UTF-8" option:

[image]

This will save the corrected file using the UTF-8 encoding:

[image]

Done!  **`:)`**

Comment: Tried "Save with encoding' but it shows previous encoding agian, in my case its UTF8

Answer (score 15):

These Windows files with Persian text are encoded in **Windows-1256**. So it can be deciphered by command similar to OP tried, but with different charsets. Namely:

<s>`recode Windows-1256..UTF-8 <Windows_file.txt > UTF8_file.txt`</s>
(denounced upon original poster’s complaints; see comments)

```
iconv -f Windows-1256 Windows_file.txt > UTF8_file.txt
```

This one assumes that the LANG environment variable is set to a UTF-8 locale. To convert to any encoding (UTF-8 or otherwise), regardless of the current locale, one can say:

```
iconv -f Windows-1256 Windows_file.txt -t ${output_encoding} > ${output_file}
```

Original poster is also confused with semantic of text recoding tools (recode, iconv). For source encoding (*source*`..` or -f) one must specify encoding with which the file is **saved** (by the program that created it). Not some (naïve) guesses based on mojibake characters in programs that try (but fail) to read it. Trying either ISO-8859-15 or WINDOWS-1252 for a Persian text was obviously an impasse: these encodings merely do not contain any Persian letter.

Comment: @Seyed Mohammad: now with commands specified explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! The second command (the one using `iconv`) worked. But the first one (using `recode`) didn't work correctly and the output was still gibberish. Edit your answer to only include the `iconv` command and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Also to be free of the LANG variable setting, one can do: `iconv -f WINDOWS-1256 -t UTF-8 in.txt > out.txt` which I tested and worked. So it may be a good idea to edit your command like this.

Comment: I wrote a useful script based on the working command which I have explained in another answer here. I hope it will help other Persian Linux-users as it help me a lot.

Comment: @karel: Thanks, “complain” is a verb – the phrase was written ungrammatically.

Comment: After testing more throughly, this method also failed to solve the problem on some real test-cases. Thus, I'm removing the solution mark.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this works with Farsi: I use Gedit, it gives a fault with wrong encoding, and I can chose what I want to translate to UTF-8, it was just text not lit format, but here is a screenshot!

[image]

Sorry I finally got through my text files, so now they are all converted.

I loved notepad++ too, miss it still.

Comment: Gedit can't fix the problem. Although Gedit doesn't show an encoding error for my file, even when it does it can't fix it. I've also tried "save as" with UTF-8 encoding in Gedit, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `iconv`, which is a very useful tool either on its own or in a script, there is a really simple solution I found trying to figure out same problem for Greek charsets (Windows-1253 + ISO-8859-7).

All you need to do is to open the text file **through Gedit's "Open" dialog** and *not by double-clicking it*. At the bottom of the dialog box there is a drop-down for Encoding, which is set to *"Automatically Detected"*. Change it to "Windows-125x" or other suitable codeset and the text will be perfectly readable in Gedit. You can then save it using UTF-8 encoding, just to be sure you won't have the same issue again in the future...

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary solution to the problem, I have prepared a useful Bash script based on the `iconv` command from [Incnis Mrsi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/662950/301745):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
   echo 'Specify at least one file to fix.'
   exit 1
fi

# Temp file to store conversion attempt(s).
tmp='tmp.fixed'

for file in "$@"
do
  # Try to fix the file encoding.
  if iconv -f WINDOWS-1256 "$file" -t UTF-8 > $tmp; then
    echo "Fixed: '$file'"
    cat $tmp > "$file"
  else
    echo "Failed to fix: '$file'"
  fi
done
rm $tmp
```

Save this script as `fix-encoding.sh`, give it execute permission using `chmod +x fix-encoding.sh` and use it like this:

```
./fix-encoding.sh myfile.txt my2ndfile.srt my3rdfile.sub
```

This script will try to fix the encoding of any number of files it is provided as input. Note that the files will be fixed in-place, so the contents will be overwritten.

Comment: You don’t need to put $file out of **"** … **"**  since variables are expanded under double quotes as well as in open text. Only **'$file'** will be rendered literally, with dollar sign, by bash.

Comment: As I mentioned in response to the answer posted by 'Incnis Mrsi', that solution failed to work and so does this script.

Answer (score 1):

If you like working in GUI instead of CLI, like I do:

1. Open file with Geany (editor)
2. Go to **File** menu -> **Reload as**
3. Choose the assumed encoding to change the gibberish into identifiable characters in your language. For example, to read Greek subs I would reload as **West European** -> **Greek (Windows-1253)**
4. Go to **Document** menu > **Set Encoding** -> **Unicode** -> **UTF-8**
5. Save

Comment: Doesn't work ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim to do the encoding conversion:

```
vim '+set fileencoding=utf-8' '+wq' file.txt
```

But this depends on Vim detecting the original encoding correctly. To make it use the correct one if it doesn't, you can do something like:

```
vim '+e ++enc=cp1256 file.txt | set fileencoding=utf-8 | wq'
```

Or, to save to a different file instead of doing it in place:

```
vim '+e ++enc=cp1256 file.txt | w ++enc=utf-8 file-utf.txt | q'
```

Comment: This is the simple solution that converted the file "in-place", meaning it would not create a new file. This was a deal-breaker for me, as SVN would see a new file instead of changes to the existing file. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it in manjaro with gaupol and work perfect but you must do it one by one and don't have batch mode

https://github.com/otsaloma/gaupol
https://pkgs.org/download/gaupol

Just open a file (no matter source encoding)
Save As (Shift + Ctrl + S)
In opened window, change Encoding to UTF-8
Hit Save and finished